# Migrating a complex branch hierarchy from SVN to Git

Tags: svn, git

How can a large SVN repository (several GBs) with hundreds of branches be migrated to a Git repository? Not looking for them to work side by side, just a way to get rid of SVN.

From some experiments I've done with `git svn` it's not clear how to specify a complex branch hierarchy. Especially when branches often get deleted in SVN...

Here's an example of the sort of hierarchy I'm talking about:

```
trunk/
tags/
vendors/boost/
branches/ProjectA/
branches/ProjectA/MajorVersion/
branches/ProjectA/MajorVersion/MinorVersion/
branches/Experimental1/
branches/RecycleBin/OldDiscardedBranch
```

The point being that a simple regex or wildcard cannot capture the correct location of all branches.

Is there a way to feed all these branch location information to Git? What will git-svn do when it tries to migrate a revision that belongs to a deleted branch?

Comment: can you be specific? what about `git svn clone --stdlayout http://url gitrepo/` does not work?

Comment: no, it doesn't, since it doesn't know how to identify which paths in the svn repository are actually branches. It just assumes a standard branch hierarchy that does not represent our particular setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking at doing similar things with a different repo.  The end result of my thinking and playing is that you need to do a few things:

- Use `git filter-branch` to do rewriting from some projects to another.  IE, use `git filter-branch` to rename everything in a sub-directory to a parent.  In my case, I have multiple modules under *trunk* and I'm using filter-branch to move everything inside one directory to the top.
- Do this for each branch as well, but also delete any branches that don't pertain to a particular project

That way in the end you'll have multiple `git` repos that contain only one project per repo (the way it should be).

If the branching/tags directories are complex, the `git svn clone` command will let you specify multiple tag and branch directories using a comma (if I recall).

Also, run `git gc --aggressive` after you've finished extracting everything to shrink the repo size a bit.

Comment: Not sure I understood. Is this something you recommend I do _after_ converting from svn to git? Also, we cannot adopt the one project per repo method. We have too many projects that share too many common libraries (hundreds).

Comment: Yes, convert the svn repo to a single git repo and then make multiple copies of it and filter each copy down to the module you want it to be.  You don't have to have multiple git repos if you don't want, but typically it's much easier and cleaner to do so.  If you have multiple libraries that affect multiple projects, that doesn't have to stop you from having them in separate modules.  You can even have a parent module contain "submodules" with all the needed pieces.

Comment: If this is generally one entire project and there isn't multiple pieces, then don't split it.  If that's the case, then you'll still need to likely use filter-branch in the strange branch cases that have major-minor versions within the branches.  It's going to take some work I think.

Comment: I still don't understand how I'm supposed to convert the repo to Git? If I just use git svn clone then I'm left with a repository where each branch is actually a directory, which means a few hundred GBs of one big corrupted repo where there is no proper branch history. In short, how can I teach svn-git what's a branch and what's not?

Comment: That's where you need to use --branches carefully in your `git svn init` (or `git svn clone`).  EG, with multiple branches: `--branches branches/ProjectA/MajorVersion/MinorVersion --branches branches/ProjectA/Experiment1` ...  You may want to perform some `svn mv`s first if it would make things easier.  IE, rename some of the depth-based branches first before running `git svn`.

Comment: Do backup the svn repo before you do anything else!

Comment: I'm trying out your suggestion, @Wes, and it seems like --branches treats its parameter as a location in which branches exist - not as a branch path. So AFAICS I cannot just specify a list of branches by doing "-b some/branch -b some/other/branch ..." - I have to first rearrange all branches into flat containers (directories that contain a single level of branches) and then do -b for each such container.